# Good practice for working with multiple solutions in Visual C# Express

Tags: c#, build-automation, visual-c#-express-2010

**Background**: My team is made up of 3 fairly inexperienced developers. We are developing in-house software for our company. Currently we have a number of smaller and separate solutions. Many of these are interdependent. Currently these depencies are made by referencing the output dll's in the respective release-folder. Updates are pushed around by manually rebuilding dependent solutions.

**Example:**
Solution A uses features of solution B. The connection is made having Solution A referencing ...\Release\B.dll . Changes to B propagates by building solution B, then building solution A and so forth.

This has worked okay before, but now we are moving from a manual (mind numbing) "version control system" (folder1, folder2, folder2New...) to using a proper one (git).

It seems that versioning the .dll's is not recommended. This means that every time someone wants to build a new version of A, he also needs to build B (and maybe 5 other solutions) in order to have the latest version of B.

I'm thinking that there must be a better way to do this.
I've been looking at combining the relevant solutions into one master solution, but I can't figure out how to do this in Visual C# Express (which we are using).

**So at long last the questions:**

1. Is having a master solution that builds everything the way to go?
   -- it seems so from MSDN but I can't figure out how to do this in Visual C# Express 2008, which leeds me to
2. Is this even possible in Visual C# Express? If not, what is a
   good way of managing the problem?

**Edit** Thanks to all for the great suggestions below. Here's a summary of what I ended up doing.

In short the answers to the questions are: "Yes" and "Sort of, but mostly yes". I implemented as follows: In order to get an idea of the dependencies, I did as suggested below, and drew a map of the binary products, with an arrow pointing from the dll's or exe's name to all of its dependencies.

For each *project*, I opened its corresponding *solution* (since at first there was *one* solution pr project). I then added the projectfile of each dependency in the tree structure revealed in the graph (by right-clicking the solution in solution explorer), so that also dependecies's dependencies and so forth were included. Then I removed the old references (pointing directly to the .dlls) and added references to the projects instead.

The important result is:

- When a solution of a project is built, all it's dependencies are built with it, so that when deploying, you know that all the build products are automatically of the latest version.

Comment: Make sure to differentiate between **projects** and **solutions**.  A project produces one dll (generally) and has a bunch of code files.  A solution is a collection of projects and is simply a way to group them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would create a new solution and add all of the projects that relate to each other to it.  You can group the projects from each of the original solutions by putting them in different solution folders within the new solution.  This way, when you build a project, all of the projects it depends upon will also get built.   It also means that all of your projects will be built using the same configuration (i.e. Release or Debug).  This means that *all* of your projects can be built in Debug, not just the top one in the dependency tree while everything below it is a Release assembly.  Makes debugging much easier.

Comment: One problem is you can't use Solution Folders in Express

Comment: @PatrickMcDonald - Oooh, that's painful.  You could use naming conventions to provide some grouping, I guess, but the lack of folders will definitely make it more annoying.

Comment: That's annoying but it shouldn't be a show-stopper. Is there any reason you can't rename your projects if you have naming collisions?

Comment: It seems I'was on the right track. Now what I can't figure out is how to make a new solution, and include specific projects in that. As in completely hands on: Which buttons do I push in VC#Express? 

I tried just drag/dropping onto the solution explorer pane, but that doesn't work. Also tried open existing file, but that seems to open the entire solution that the project was in before.

Comment: Right click on the solution in Solution Explorer, click Add > Existing Project, browse to the project you want to add to the solution.

Answer (score 4):

I have Visual C# Express 2010 and when I create a new project, it automatically creates a default solution. If it's visible, then you can right-click on the solution and choose Add>Existing Project.

If the solution is not visible, (I seem to remember this problem in C# Express 2005/8), then you can add an existing project via File>Add>Existing Project. The solution should be visible now.

In terms of speration, what I usually do is this:

Everything that must be built together should be in one solution, and these should be projects and not DLL's. I try to live by [The Joel List](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000043.html), where you should be able to build your project in one step. If it is one deployable unit, then there should be one solution. All of my projects are built on a build server before they can be deployed, so everything should be in the solution that needs to be built.

Guys sometimes put the WCF services project and the clients in the same project for easy debugging, but it depends on whether you want to deploy client and server independently. Usually for bigger projects I separate them.

Lastly there's one exception. We have a central common library that is used by different teams. If it's included in different solutions, and one team changes something, we end up breaking the other team's builds. In this case, we create a single solution that has all of the library projects. These get built to DLL's that we store the versions of. We treat these as a framework that the other solutions can use. E.g. Team A is using CommonLibrary 1.1 and Team B is using CommonLibrary 1.2.

Answer (score 2):

You need to think of Solutions as just "groupings of projects" - the projects are what are actually "built", not the "solution" (well, that's not *entirely* true, the solution is turned into a "metaproject" that references the contained projects, but its close enough to the truth)

If you have interdependencies between solutions, I would suggest drawing all the projects on a big whiteboard, then draw arrows representing the dependencies from project to project. Once you've done this, you'll be able to see at a glance what the appropriate "groupings of projects" make sense. Those become your solution files.

For example, if you have projects A, B, ..., F, where:

- A depends on B
- B depends on C
- D depends on C
- E depends on F

One possible split here would be solution 1 with projects A, B, C, D and solution 2 with projects E, F.

Answer (score -4):

I would come up with a common area to push all dlls.  My company uses the "R" drive, which is just a LOCAL (not network so no one can touch another persons folder) mapped folder everyone has.  Each solution will build to this.  Right click a project, properties->build and change the output.  Or you can add a post build command to push the dll there.  After that, have all of your projects reference this location.

Once this is done and everything is pointing at the same place, you can even add different combinations of projects to different solutions.  If a developer only wants the ui projects, they can open a special "ui" solution that is a subset of the whole.

Here is a post build event that I use in my project properties->build events

```
rem when building on local workstation copy dll to local R:\
if '$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' (
    xcopy $(TargetDir)$(TargetName).* R:\Extranet\$(TargetName)\1.0\  /Y
)
rem if "Enterprise" build then copy dll to Corp R:\ drive and to Build Machine R:\
if '$(Reason)' == 'Manual' (
    xcopy $(TargetDir)$(TargetName).* \\folder\$(TargetName)\1.0\ /Y
    xcopy $(TargetDir)$(TargetName).* R:\Extranet\$(TargetName)\1.0\ /Y
)
```

Comment: This is a really bad idea.  What happens if you're working on some change and you do a build, and your coworker is working on a different change and builds slightly after you?  Your dlls with your code changes will be replaced by theirs, and your code will break for no apparent reason.

Comment: This is designed for disaster!

Comment: Debugging and configuration management in this environment would be a nightmare.

Comment: I think that you misunderstood.  Everyone has a locally mapped folder with the same drive letter.  No one has access to anyone elses machine.  How is this bad at all?

Comment: I updated my comment to reflect this.  I also have comments in the post build which were always there that say it is a local copy.

Comment: @user957863 - I removed my downvote, since it isn't the disaster it appeared to be.  However, what's the advantage to doing it this way? You're still going to have outdated DLLs sitting there unless you open every solution and rebuild them.  It's no different from referencing the DLL from it's default build location.

Comment: I use this at work with a big team and it works well.Create one solution with proj1-proj4.  All dlls point to the same location, they are all in the same solution no issues.  If someone needed just proj1 and proj2, they could have another solution that uses only has those projects.  You can open and build them as necessary.  dll3 and dll4 aren't old because you haven't change the code.  If you do change code, build and you are all set.  This works very well especially if you have contractors that only get a subset of the code.  The don't see the code for proj3 but still have access to the dll.

Comment: Also consider if you have multiple projects that use the same third party dll.  If you keep them in one location you only have to update that one part and everything will work.  If you plan to copy everything to the bin, you will have to keep track of this.  Or you can mix and match using the bin and a common area, but this is sloppy.

Comment: @user957863 - You're still either checking in the DLL or else it's old.  If I make major breaking changes to `proj3`, the person who needs `proj1` and `proj2` either has to grab the latest version of the DLL from source control, or else they have to realize they need to open `proj3` and build it.  If they don't do that, when they check their changes in, it will break even more things because it was written using the old `proj3.dll`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are talking about, when did I say check anything into source control.  I am simply saying instead of using the bin directory local to a solution, use a local folder that follows the same naming convention on every machine.  I am not sure why people think that copying dlls to each and every project you have is a good solution.  How is using bin better than R: (when R is simply a folder on my machine)?

Comment: @user957863 - Well, if you don't check them into source control, then you have to manually open every solution and build it to create the DLL.  And they'll *always* be out of date.  The advantage of copying the DLLS to each and every project is that Visual Studio will handle it for you so you don't need to think about it, and you only end up with the dlls you need.

Comment: If you don't update code, nothing is out of date.  If you do update code run it at least once to test.  R: vs bin is exactly the same.   So if you have a third party dll that is needed in 5 solutions, how do you handle that?  As a follow up question, when you need to update the third party dll how do you handle that?

Comment: @user957863 - But what if *someone else* updated code?  It would be out of date then.   We handle third party dlls by committing them (once!) to a "Library" folder, and then adding a reference to it using the relative path.  Visual Studio copies them into any project that references them when they're built.  If we needed to update it, we'd commit the new version into the library, and the next time the code was built, it would copy it in again.

Comment: So we agree on third party dlls.  I am not sure how my answer indicated that all the code would not be in the same solution.  If someone updates code build it and run it.  Imagine mapping R: to your bin folder.  Nothing changes at all.  They are 100% equivalent.  If you have a new developer only working on one project that was not able to touch the others because of security concerns, you can create a new solution, add one project and my solution works.  Your solution would require copying dlls all over the place.  We have a script that handles third party dlls or company wide solutions.