# Create project and its own sln file within multiple project solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, solution, sln-file

We have a large server-side C# solution at work. It has multiple projects, each with its own `sln` file on the first layer of the application's directory.  It also has a general `all.sln` which contains all the projects.

I have added a new project which builds successfully, but a `sln` file for this individual project has not been created.  How can I create it in VS 2013, so it appears alongside the other `sln` files?

Any help at all would be appreciated.  I need to do this so that the BAT file we're using has a `sln` file it can use.

---

Comment: I think you mean multiple `Project`s in a `Solution`.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606770/good-practice-for-working-with-multiple-solutions-in-visual-c-sharp-express) for more information.

Comment: Basically your boss just arranged the files system into single sln for better maintenance. what you do now is, 1) create a independent fresh project (outside of this solution) 2) ensure you copy that under respective directory ofr other projects and sln that is refereed. 3) Now open the main solution and hide/show menu items in solution explorer and include the folder 4) thats all.

Comment: Thanks Gomes. That managed to work. It seems like a roundabout way of doing it, but VS doesn't seem to offer any alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create an empty solution, save it at the proper location with the proper name, and add the desired project to it.

To create the empty solution:

```
File > New Project >
    Other Project Types > Visual Studio Solutions > 
        Blank Solution
```